# NSSharingService set CC and BCC recipients in Default Email MAC OSX Application

Tags: macos, email, cocoa, desktop-application

I am new to Mac OS X application development, My question is simple, i am able set recipients  and body text in default mail application through my application, but i cannot set CC and BCC recipients in the mail application. Is there any way to set CC and BCC through code, i am using Swift. 
My Code for settings recipients and Body is here

```
 service!.recipients = [self.txtTo.stringValue]
 service!.subject = "Subject"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's generally much easier to just use a mailto URL for this case - all mail applications support them (and its required as a URL scheme for an app to be registered as an email application).

Here's the [schema](https://yoast.com/dev-blog/guide-mailto-links/).

An example would be:

```
mailto:a@b.com?subject=blah&cc=b@c.com,c@d.com&bcc=d@e.com,e@f.com
```

You can generate and open this URL using

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:a@b.com?subject=blah&cc=b@c.com,c@d.com&bcc=d@e.com,e@f.com"]]
```

Comment: in swift it will be like this     NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(NSURL.init(string:"mailto:\(self.txtTo.stringValue)"+"?subject=YourSubject"+"&cc="+self.txtCC.stringValue+"&bcc="+self.txtBcc.stringValue)!)

Comment: I have one more question regarding this, can we add attachments using NSWorkspace? @Dev

Answer (score 1):

I had to tinker with it a bit to get it to work in Swift 5. This is what I came up with:

```
let url = URL.init(string: "mailto:\a@b.com?subject=\(subject)&cc=b@c.com,c@d.com&bcc=d@e.com,e@f.com")
NSWorkspace.shared.open(url!)
```