# Is there a way to include fields such as "BCC" and "CC" using NSSharingService?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nssharingservice

Im wondering if there is a way to compose an email in Swift and have it populate fields such as CC and BCC.

Currently I am using NSSharingService and it only appears to have the options for Recipient, Subject, and Body.

I'm not married to using NSSharingService, but I would like to know a way to implement what I am trying to do.

EDIT: I am developing for Mac and not iOS

```
class SendEmail: NSObject {
    static func send(recipient: String) {
        let service = NSSharingService(named: 
        service.recipients = ["Recipient Goes Here"]
        service.subject = "Subject Goes Here"
        service.perform(withItems: ["Body Goes Here"])
    }
}
```

Comment: It would appear that NSSharingService doesn't offer such a thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660096/nssharingservice-set-cc-and-bcc-recipients-in-default-email-mac-osx-application/39673723

Comment: I have tried the solution in the link posted by @pompopo but I get all kinds of errors. I assume the post being three years old some of the classes used are deprecated. I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'openURL'" "Use of unresolved identifier 'sharedWorkspace'" or "Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSWorkspace'" along with a few syntax error. I'm assuming that I am the one doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

This works in Swift5 (Xcode 10.2.1, macOS 10.14.5)

```swift
let url = URL(string: "mailto:to@example.com?subject=subject&cc=cc@example.com&bcc=bcc@example.com")!
NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it.